# Swipe to change label content in swift

Tags: ios, swift, label, swipe

I'm a beginner in coding and I have this question:

Example, I have 4 different labels with their own messages.

Label1 - you should read the rules
 Label2 - congratulations you read the rules
 Label3 - now you can join us
 Label4 - welcome aboard

I want to be able to do something like this:

Label1 is shown, swipe right > label2 appears > swipe right > label3 appears > swipe right > label4 appears
 I also want to be able to swipe left and return to the previous label.

Ex.
label1>label2>label3

Comment: `UICollectionView` with paging enabled would be a pretty simple solution... but beyond that this question is unclear/too broad.

Comment: I'll try the collectionview, I'll let you know how it plays out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep each label in an array, create a counter and in the swipe method increase or decrease de counter value to select the corresponding label with the array index of the counter.

Like so:

Swipe right:

counter+=1
currentLabel = labelsArray[counter] as! UILabel

Swipe left:

counter-=1
currentLabel = labelsArray[counter] as! UILabel

But why not use a collectionview instead? You can make it paged and it'll be something that the users are more used to.

Comment: Like I said I'm brand new to swift and coding, counter sounds like a plan but I'll try the collectionview and let you know how it works, thanks!